# Try-catch handler and DivideByZeroException

Tags: c#, try-catch

I have some function ,that calculate numbers and i catch exceptions:

```
try{
....
 return mainCount /count;
}
 catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
        {

            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return 0;
        }
```

So, is that catch right? Or may be program should crash?

Thank you!

Comment: It wont crash but why dont you give it a try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Never*** catch `Exception` (base class) *without throw*: it means "whatever had happened just return zero". It's not a desired behaviour in case, say, of internal .Net error or RAM corruption...

```
  try { 
    ...
    return mainCount / count;
  }
  catch (DivideByZeroException) { // <- You don't need instance ("ex") here
    // quite OK: return 0 when count == 0
    return 0;
  }
```

Better practice, however, is just test if `count == 0`:

```
  return count == 0 ? 0 : mainCount / count;
```

typical pattern with `Exception` catch

```
  try {
    ...
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    // Whatever had happend, write error to log
    SaveToLog(e, ...);
    // And throw the exception again
    throw; // <- not "throw e;"! 
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use exceptions to dictate the flow of your program, you can easily see what error might occur here so I suggest the following

```
if(count == 0)
    return 0;
return mainCount / count;
```

Catching exceptions should only be done to catch the unexpected